# Why can we not use TangoService_connectTextureId() and TangoService_connectOnFrameAvailable() simultaneously?

Tags: android, android-camera, google-project-tango

Why can we not use `TangoService_connectTextureId()` and  `TangoService_connectOnFrameAvailable()` simultaneously? ([see C API](https://developers.google.com/project-tango/apis/c/group__camera)) I want to display the color camera image, so I would like to use TangoService_connectTextureId(). However,

I also want to access the camera pixels to do some image processing, so I would also like to use `TangoService_connectOnFrameAvailable().` Is there a reasonable explanation why I cannot use both of these function simultaneously? What's the best alternative in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Use connectOnFrameAvailable and then use the image to create your own texture - going the other way might leave trying to figure out how to pry the texture back out of the GPU